# Trying to "Pulse" DateTime Updates in WPF App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I apologize up front for the lengthy explication.

I am working on a WPF desktop app (shown below):

[image]

Basically there can be 0..n process status items in the list (the items themselves are ListBoxItems rendered using a DataTemplate). Recently, I decided I wanted to provide a "time elapsed" style presentation (n seconds/minutes/hours ago) as an alternative to an absolute DateTime format (mm/dd/yyyy at HH:mm:ss). I've accomplished this by using a MultiBinding to a TextBlock as such:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter = "{StaticResource timeElapsedConverter}">
            <Binding 
                Path   = "StatusDateTime"
            />
            <Binding 
                Source = "{StaticResource propertiesHelper}" 
                Path   = "UserOptions.UseElapsedTimeStamps" 
            />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

I'll spare you the details of the IMultiValueConverter implementation. The second binding is to a helper class that gets the user's timestamp display preferences (i.e. they can still see absolute DateTime values if they want to). The "StatusDateTime" property to which this TextBlock is otherwise bound is nothing special; it's just a POCO property in a ViewModel class that fires OnPropertyChanged when set.

This view is synchronized with the system backend every (x) seconds. I'd like to "Pulse" the timestamps during synchronization so that the elapsed time measurements stay accurate but if I just set the StatusDateTime property to its existing value, nothing seems to happen (in the case of the example below, it will just say "Published 6 seconds ago..." until either the process itself is updated on the server side or until the application is loaded a second time).

I tried adding IsAsync="true" to the StatusDateTime binding as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199822/inotifypropertychanged-does-not-work-when-the-property-set-to-a-same-value-for-th), but to no avail.

I also tried falling back to regular binding (non-multi) with Mode="TwoWay" explicity declared and that didn't work either.

I know I could just blow away the list and recreate during synchronization, but that just doesn't seem very elegant when I already have all the data I need loaded into the client.

**Update:** I tried recreating this basic setup in a Window and it seemed to work just fine. I'm now wondering if this has something to do with the target control being on a Page or part of a DataTemplate.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you fire OnPropertyChanged.  Verify that you are firing NotifyPropertyChanged("StatusDateTime");  Can't take it for granted.

Comment: So you compare a DateTime variable to DateTime.Now() and display the resulting TimeSpan?

Comment: @BahriGungor - I verified that the PropertyChanged event for the StatusDateTime field is firing.

Comment: @Baboon - No, I am binding to the StatusDateTime property in my ViewModel class and am expecting that said binding will cause the UI to update when the underlying property value is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I believe I've figured it out. I left out a key piece of detail that more quickly would've pointed us in the right direction: My `DataTemplate` is backed by a `CollectionViewSource`. If I call the Refresh() method on the `CollectionViewSource`'s `View` property, the timestamps update as expected. I always forget that changing properties of elements of an `ObservableCollection` doesn't necessarily cause the `CollectionChanged` event to fire which would thereby prompt the `CollectionViewSource` to refresh.

Thanks to all who replied!

Comment: That's functionally equivalent to calling `OnPropertyChanged` on every element :) Good job though. You may be interested in a `BindingList<T>` rather than an `ObservableCollection`, actually - it's a special collection that actually listens to `INotifyPropertyChanged` notifications from its items, meaning that changing properties of individual elements correctly propagates the change as you would expect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655158/how-can-i-detect-changes-to-item-properties-in-the-bindinglistt

Answer (score 2):

The way I accomplished this in my own MVVM based app was to have a simple timer running on my ViewModel that fires `OnPropertyChanged` every second for the property I want to keep updated. Here's an example (in IronPython syntax):

```
self.displayTimer = System.Timers.Timer(1000) #fire every second
self.displayTimer.Elapsed += self.displayTimer_Tick
self.displayTimer.Start()

def displayTimer_Tick(self, sender, event):
    self.OnPropertyChanged("StatusDateTime")
```

This uses a `System.Timers.Timer` that executes its callback on a background `ThreadPool` thread, so it won't interfere with the Dispatcher.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I'm still hoping there's a pure MVVM way to get this to work.

Comment: This **is** MVVM. ;) You are explicitly avoiding referencing controls in the View; instead, you raise INotifyPropertyChanged notifications from the ViewModel, which signal all bindings bound to that property to fetch a new value.

Comment: I agree with Aphex.  MVVM is more about the separation of dependency than it is about threading.  You might, however, want to spin the thread at a higher level to send the notification for all of the processes running, instead of spinning N threads for N processes.

Comment: Point taken. I'm actually doing something like what @BahriGungor is suggesting (a synchronization thread at a higher level that covers all items). But the problem isn't with the choice of implementation, it's that it's not actually updating the UI in response to the PropertyChanged event like it seems it should be.